# How to remove duplicate values in tensor in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, duplicates, tensor, word-embedding

I'm dealing with word embedding recently, and here is the problem I face right now.
I will have duplicated value in tensor. Suppose I have the following 2D tensor in shape(?, 5)

**input**

```
[[1 2 4 2 6]
 [7 2 6 1 2]
 [7 2 6 1 2]
 [3 9 3 9 2]
 [3 9 3 9 2]
 [4 9 8 1 6]
 [4 9 8 1 6]]
```

**expected output**

```
[[1 2 4 2 6]
 [7 2 6 1 2]
 [3 9 3 9 2]
 [4 9 8 1 6]]
```

I do some survey in the community. I still cannot address this problem specificly. Is there any method I can solve the duplicated issue in tensorflow?

Answer (score -1):

you can use [tf.unique(x)](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/unique)

```
u, idx = tf.unique(x)
print(u)
# [[1 2 4 2 6]
# [7 2 6 1 2]
# [3 9 3 9 2]
# [4 9 8 1 6]]
```

Comment: Hi @Marceline, thanks for the response. I followed your strategy and got the following error track from TensorFlow. ```Shape must be rank 1 but is rank 2 for 'Unique_76' (op: 'Unique') with input shapes: [7,5].``` It looks like we have to make x in rank 1, because tf.unique() doesn't accept rank2 Tensor as input. Can you share how did you apply your strategy in this question?

Comment: seems like tf.unique only works on 1D tensor at the moment. have you solve this? @Heng-ShiouSheu